# How to make sure, that certain functionality (like Alt+Ctrl+F1 switching into tty) is available in havily swapping system?

Tags: linux, kernel, memory

At the moment, when I accidentally launch application that eats a lot of memory (that causes system to heavily swap), the system become so unresponsive (waiting hours just to see the mouse move/or switching to the tty1 with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) that it effectively means I need to REISUB (= hard reboot) and lost ALL of my current, not saved work.

In Windows world, some parts of the kernel are never swapped out (like mouse movement or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> combination) and even in a very bad out-of-memory situation I can recover in under 5 minutes by calling Task Manager and killing the offending application.

Surely I must be missing something, I can't imagine that the whole Linux system can be brought to its knees with something so simple and innocent as preview with imagemagick a multi page tiff book (the imgemagick happens to load all the pages of the image uncompressed into the memory first…)

I heard about the experimental [BFQ I/O scheduler](http://algo.ing.unimo.it/people/paolo/disk_sched/), maybe this could help?

Answer (score 3):

Believe. :(.  I assume we're considering a single-user system here, so SaK (kill your entire login) doesn't really help.

Know your hard disk activity indicators.  Know how to take something down  quickly.  Sometimes it might save you, sometimes it won't.

Swap used to work tolerably.  Now RAM is faster and bigger, hard drives are bigger but the relative speed (and particularly random-access) is terrible.  Windows put a fair amount of work in setting an upper bound on the horribleness.  Linux hasn't and just lets you shoot yourself.

If you have sufficient RAM and don't need hibernation, you can consider disabling swap.  If you need hibernation... you need a swap space the same size as your ram :(.  It's certainly possible to script.  Official support is probably lacking, though at least pm-utils has a nice architecture for installing your own hooks.  (Add a custom swap device before suspend & remove it after resume; you may also need to add a resume= boot option).

That said, ctrl+alt+f1 will work better if you have kernel mode switching.  (Otherwise the X server has to do some work, and it's a userspace process.  The entire kernel is always in RAM, unlike Windows where some parts can get swapped out).  Binary drivers like nvidia's are not your friend here.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. Do you know, if Ubuntu uses KSM by default? I think it does, but I couldn't find any reference.

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski If you're talking about page merging, [you can easily check that](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/KSM) just see if you have a non-zero shared_pages without having started a scan yourself. You can always initiate the first scan if you determine you need it.

Comment: @Joel Thank you very much. I was meaning KMS (sorry for typo). Fortunately I've learned something interesting about the kernel... So, do you know by chance, whether Ubuntu uses KMS by default?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I'm willing to bet so. You can check `dmesg` to see if the direct render stuff loaded at boot and started working. [Here](http://dpaste.org/EEmPV/) is an example from my Fedora box.

Comment: Which version :P  Any recent version will use kernel mode switching by default.  The intel X driver (I think) dropped support for user mode switching a while back.  Some old drivers don't support it at all though.

Answer (score 3):

**Firstly, sorry for the length of this post**

At the risk of sounding like a FOSS cliche, in response to the comparison made with Windows task manager:

One thing that will make it easier to understand why some thing on GNU/Linux are designed the way they are is to just remind yourself that Windows isn't the reference point for most Linux distributions' design (except maybe Ubuntu). For example, Red Hat is a billion dollar corporation but they got there by marketing themselves to enterprise users as being an affordable easier-to-use alternative to traditional (proprietary) Unix vendors and competing against OS's like HP-UX Solaris, AIX, etc. Most Unix deployments are in high end data centers, so Unix has been designed from square one with the idea that anyone doing maintenance on it will have a certain level of technical know-how and will value things like systemic inertness, clearly defined transform processes, and high levels of granular control.

This (rational) mindset is in direct opposition to Window's design: put everything on rails putting you towards a single basic solution that you can then brand as your own, make a few basic changes to configuration, and maybe, if you're an advanced user, go in and change some "low level" stuff (Unix Admins' conception of "low level" and Windows Admins' differ considerably as a result of this design difference). To Windows admins checking/changing the HMAC for AD's Kerberos server is considered being l33t (At least I hope the average AD admin is just unaware of AD's use of MD4 hashes) whereas on Unix HMAC, password hasing, etc is just part of setting up the server, just being some of those the things you're supposed to think about when designing your company's solution.

This isn't to say that putting things on rails in order to reduce the amount of time consumed by deployment is necessarily bad, sometimes you just need a solution and the value contributed through administrative control doesn't make that level of explicitness worthwhile. This is why Red Hat still develops things like FreeIPA (point and click Identity management) and ktune (basic performance tuning by selecting the "profile" that best matches your intended use of the system). But from the Unix perspective, most MS products are considered to be software that encourages poor administrative work ethic (by misinforming you of what kind of workflow is most efficient) especially if it's used for literally every single problem that comes across your desk. It makes your job easier, but you're robbing your employer of efficiency.

I could kind of belabor the point (too late, right?) and start talking about some of the things Windows does that make no technical sense but got implemented anyways, but you get the idea.

There's a lot of chest beating and posturing from Unix/Linux admins in regards to Window's design (and some of it is just "haters gonna hate" or ego stroking on the part of the speaker) but if you dig into the argument long enough you'll see that there is a fundamental ideological divide on how the OS should behave and what your style of management ought to be.

**To answer the issue, though:**

It's not a design deficiency that Linux is letting the system get bogged down like that, it's a design choice. You can argue about defaults, but Unix is designed with the idea that the admin ought to understand *exactly* what the system is doing. In the targe work environment, "it's just how Unix does it" is not an acceptable answer. Your boss is going to want to be confident that you knew exactly what happened when trouble came up and that you have the problem beat at a fundamental level so that it doesn't come back up again.

With the expectation that administrator will value explicitness and systemic inertness over opaque automated platform processes, it's left up to the admin to determine what kind of solution they want to implement (how does a software vendor, you never interact with directly, know what your company needs and provide it out of the box?). Unix/Linux provide the basic mechanisms for you to do your work with (hopefully ones that prevent you from being redundant, "DRY" and all that), but they won't try to develop the final solution for you.

What you might be interested in is looking into kernel mechanisms like [OOM killer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html) which will kill runaway processes either system-wide or on a per process basis (see previous jump for how to do that). [Cgroups](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt) are currently the preferred mechanism for controlling resource usage, but [limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf) has existed for quite a while, and can set limits based on username or group membership (but it's on a per-session basis).

If a particular user or group is bogging down the system, the design assumption on the vendor's side is that you must not *want* to put limits on the process (perhaps to gracefully accommodate temporary spikes, or to squeeze more performance out of the system by avoiding restrictive caps on the application, ones that might cause undesirable application performance/behavior) and so will let processes go up to OOM killing limits,.

If that's not the case, you need to do something with cgroups or limits.conf so that whatever software is causing this problem is contained and doesn't bring the system down. This is in contrast to your expected Windows behavior, where (in this case) they don't really give you an opt-in or opt-out they just kind of *just do it* one way, and if that's not ideal for how you think or for business processes then you're just going to need to learn to deal with it. A lot of Windows' design hides intentional design choices behind decent admins telling non-technical people (in good faith) that "that's just not how the system works" or "that's not how computers work" which is basically a thought killing set of logic they're encouraging the admins to take on.

Ultimately, you need to be concerned with fixing the problem as well as containing it and egressing from it. For platform design, I could see an argument for adding Xorg and its descendants to some sort of default cgroup that you could then target, but you would have to take that up with Canonical (I'm assuming this is on Ubuntu from your other comments). There's some underlying reason this issue is happening and it needs to be resolved through one of these: 1) additional hardware capacity 2) limiting/allocating application access to said capacity 3) resolving application-level errors like memory leaks or software bugs.

Hauke's idea about carving out a particular tty for system recovery is actually a pretty good one given what you're saying you prefer. I added an addendum on it to get it even closer to the mark. That's a particular solution you can develop for yourself, there are a nearly infinite set of permutations you could figure out for yourself, though.

Comment: I agree with one point here - _if_ you hit this a lot, you need to fix the cause :).  Maybe you don't have enough RAM for the sort of things you try.  Maybe you need to avoid certain pathological files... or make sure the apps that act pathologically aren't part of your environment.  Evince used to act like this but has since improved - and it can open tiffs.

Comment: Well, if the OP is having hardware capacity issues, then he has a fix, it's just not one they may be able to implement because of the money involved. In that case containing the problem with cgroups is probably the best workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be reduced if you give CPU and I/O real time priority to one of the gettys. You may also create another user with UID 0 and make its shell a path to a ramdisk with a statically linked shell. And keep reading `/etc/passwd` every few seconds so that it stays in the cache.

The better approach may be to have a process running which stops processes which consume to much RAM.

**Edit 1:**

Another idea: You could start top as root within screen (both with real time priority) on one virtual console and lock screen automatically. Thus you would need the root password to use top but the advantage would be that the process(es) you need would already be running. And as they were actively doing something they would not get swapped out but consume both little CPU and little memory.

Comment: I'll try them and see, how much it really helps. Thank you!

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski See my edit.

Comment: Yes. I'd love to see it in action. I'll do the testing after I finish my work.

Comment: @HaukeLaging One thing to note is that processes started in this tty will inherit the real time priority (for both I/O and CPU), so it's advisable to only use that to replicate the mentioned behavior with Windows Task Manager. If you don't treat it as an escape hatch and you accidentally kick off the taxing operation from that tty things could get worse (per-process I/O priority also presumes cfq and that doesn't exist on the other I/O schedulers).

Comment: One idea springboarding off this, you can configure the login script for root to perpetually launch/re-launch top if it sees itself on the given tty. The script could also be what sets the real-time priority on the `top` process (you'd want to make sure you had a longish refresh delay set to minimize the impact of this, though). A lot of tty managers can also be configured to automatically log a particular user in. This would essentially re-create the exact behavior they're noticing Windows task manager (just a text-based version).

Comment: @JoelDavis That's why my proposal (in German and from the pre-systemd age though) contains a warning which is issued at login to that shell. :-)  http://www.hauke-laging.de/software/emergency-root-shell/

Answer (score 2):

As you noted that SysRq still responds, you could adjust the offending processes' OOM priority. The adjustment is done by writing to `/proc/XYZ/oom_score_adj`, where XYZ is the process ID. If the processes get out of hand, kill one of them with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> if necessary.

Here's my script that does this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# match any process containing "thunderb" or "chrome" - that's specific enough for me
for i in `ps ax | grep -E 'thunderb|chrome' | cut -f1 "--delimiter= "` ; do
        fname=/proc/$i/oom_score_adj
        if [ -f "$fname" ] ; then
                # the higher the score, the more likely the process is 
                #  to be chosen by the OOM killer
                echo '900' > $fname
        fi
done
```

Note that you need to run this script as root, and it will only affect already existing processes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had a lot of swap on hard drive (+ zram), so it is never even close to OOM condition. But than, maybe I should trim the swap. Too bad, that it would require repartitioning the whole hard drive...

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski I always LVM every single partition except the boot partition for this reason. Might be a good practice to adopt.

Comment: @patrick You are right, and I think I exagerated with the partitioning stuff; I have GPT and everything beside swap is btrfs, so actually it will be fairly easy to change the size of the swap. I just got surprised to the thought that system freezes under memory congestion has something to do with the partitioning scheme :-)

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski btw, you don't technically need a swap partition. There are marginal performance benefits to using a parition over file (sometimes makes math converting offset in the swap source to a sector more direct) but if the memory manager has to go to disk, that's the most expensive part of the operation by far (ie: performance gains of partition is dwarfed). LVM can do swap volumes, but you can't do that with btrfs. With btrfs (and in general) you might do well to go with a swap file instead. This is the same thing Windows does.

Comment: The SysRq combination directly triggers the OOM killer regardless of actual memory conditions. (It's a bit of a hack, yes)